# Applying a theme to v7 Support Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-support-library

I am using the support v7 library to implement `ActionBar` in my app..I have this in my `styles.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

However, Eclipse complains in the `actionBarStyle` line. The error is this one:

`android:actionBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 8)`

What can I do to apply my theme to API levels 8-10?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to provide two API specific styles.xml. In your values/styles.xml use

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

and in your values-v14/styles.xml use

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: wouldn't you swap `AppCompat` to `Holo` for `values-v14/styles.xml`??

Comment: Theme.AppCompat is derived from Holo for API 14+. So you don't have to do it yourself. This helps to keep your code consistent.

Comment: @hitmaneidos, It's better to use `Holo` instead of `AppCompat` because when you no longer need to support old versions, removing the "compatiblity part" is straightforward.

Comment: That would have made sense earlier, but with the new AppCompat providing material theme for all versions before Lollipop its no longer the case. You'll have to wait a very long time before removing the "compatibility" part.

Comment: Why does ActionBar it not show up in the preview mode even if I changed the theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you use latest v7 support library (v21 at the time of this post), there is no need to add `android:` prefix to any action bar attributes anymore.

In your case, adding the following to `values/styles.xml` will be sufficient:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

Reference: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#migration-from-previous-setup

Comment: Can you please post the complete styles.xml with ActionBarTheme example as well? I've been trying for hours with no success :(

Comment: <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <!-- Customize action bar here -->
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    </style>

I extend from AppCompat style, you can browse it to see what are available to override.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm overriding wrong properties (`background`, `textColor`). I noticed that ActionBar title responded to TextView background / color changes when I was doing those.

Comment: Finally figured it out: title bar wasn't working for me because I had also set android:background for the entire theme.

Comment: Vote for my post if it's helpful to you. Thank you.