# Customizing default Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert with android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I've recently switch the `AlertDialog` instances in my app to use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, but am having a problem applying a custom theme and style to the alert dialogs.

In my *styles.xml* I have the following style:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent_1</item>
    <item name="background">@color/theme_component_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/theme_component_background</item>
</style>
```

In my *themes.xml* I have the following set in my theme as required:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
```

For some reason the custom styles are never applied to the `AlertDialog` instances, and they remain the default `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert` theme.

If I explicitly set the style resource to use as follows, it does work:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialog);
```

Is there no way to set the default style across the entire theme and not have to specify the theme in the `Builder` constructor?

Comment: Read it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307622/applying-a-theme-to-v7-support-action-bar. Does it help you?

Answer (score 8):

As per Pankaj Kumar's response, the link details the solution, which is to have both declarations with and without the "android:" prefix in the name attribute.

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
```